# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, ZipFile found

Tags: python, unicode, tcp, network-programming, zip

I have a server which is supposed to ask the client for a file, compress it and send it to the client. I'm having a little bit of trouble being able to send the zip file to the server.

This is the Error i am receiving:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "/Users/Alcantara/Desktop/Final/Server.py", line 9, in RetrFile
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(Zip):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 278, in walk
names = listdir(top)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, ZipFile found
```

This is my Server:

```
import socket
import threading
import os
import zipfile

def RetrFile(name, sock):
    Zip = sock.recv(1024)
    Zip = zipfile.ZipFile("new_" + Zip +".zip", "w")
    for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(Zip):
        Zip.write(dirname)
        for filename in files:
            Zip.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
    Zip.close()
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
        sock.send(bytesToSend)
        while bytesToSend != "":
            bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
            sock.send(bytesToSend)

    sock.close()

def Main():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 5000


    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host,port))

    s.listen(5)

    print "Server Started."
    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print "client connedted ip:<" + str(addr) + ">"
        t = threading.Thread(target=RetrFile, args=("RetrThread", c))
        t.start()

    s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Client:

```
import socket

def Main():
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 5000

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host, port))

filename = raw_input("Filename? -> ")
if filename != 'q':
    s.send(filename)
    f = open('new_'+filename, 'wb')
    data = s.recv(1024)
    totalRecv = len(data)
    f.write(data)
    while totalRecv < filesize:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        totalRecv += len(data)
        f.write(data)
        print "{0:.2f}".format((totalRecv/float(filesize))*100)+ "% Done"
        print "Download Complete!"
    f.close()
else:
    print "File Does Not Exist!"

s.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: What certainly your send to server? Path to file? Or path to directory with files?

Comment: i sent the path to directory with files. i want to compress the directory (including the files in it) and send it to client as a zip file .

Answer (score 1):

Consider these lines:

```
Zip = sock.recv(1024)
Zip = zipfile.ZipFile("new_" + Zip +".zip", "w")
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(Zip):
```

You are using the same variable name to refer to the received data (lines 1 and 3) and also a `ZipFile` object (line 2).

Try this instead:

```
#UNTESTED
zname = sock.recv(1024)
zfile = zipfile.ZipFile("new_" + Zip +".zip", "w")
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(zname):
    zfile.write(dirname)
    for filename in files:
        zfile.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
zfile.close()
with open("new_" + zname + ".zip", 'rb') as f:
    # ... the rest is unchanged
```

Comment: By using your correction i got this error: AttributeError: '_socketobject' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: My bad. you can't use `shutil.copyfileobj` that way.

Comment: I have a working script that compresses files and a working Server/Client that transfers files. I just need to know how would i be able to combine them into one script.